How to get a radial gradiant/box-shadow to start from the center of a box and then go past the border
How do I get it so that if I have an image in a div, or just a div in general, and i want to have a glow coming from the middle of that div and expand out past the border of the div but it still be a singular continuous gradient? and not have an irregular break going from inside the the border to outside the border?
Here is my HTML snippet:
<div class="stats-grid">
                <div class="stat-item championships">
                    <img class="stat-label" src="../../assets/noto-v1--trophy.png" alt="overlay image" style="height: 64px;width: 64px">
                  <span class="stat-value trophyValue">3</span> <!-- Example value -->
                </div>
                <div class="stat-item">
                  <span class="stat-label">WINS:</span>
                  <span class="stat-value">20</span> <!-- Example value -->
                </div>
                <div class="stat-item">
                    <span class="stat-label">DRAWS:</span>
                    <span class="stat-value">5</span> <!-- Example value -->
                  </div>
                <div class="stat-item">
                  <span class="stat-label">LOSSES:</span>
                  <span class="stat-value">5</span> <!-- Example value -->
                </div>
                <div class="stat-item">
                  <span class="stat-label">WIN %:</span>
                  <span class="stat-value">80%</span> <!-- Example value -->
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>

and then here is my CSS:
 .stats-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 20px;
    background-color: #192842;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    align-items: start; /* Aligns items to the start of the grid area */
  }
  
  .championships {
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;
    justify-self: center; /* Centers the championships item */
    align-items: center;
    /* color: #111; */
    /* background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(255,204,0,0.7) 0%, rgba(255,204,0,0) 100%); */
    /* left: 50%; */
    /* top: 0; */
    
    box-shadow: 0 0 100px rgba(255,204,0,0.7);
    border-radius: 10px;
    /* background:transparent !important;
    background-color: transparent !important; */
  }
.stat-item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: #101f3c;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  
  
  .stat-label {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; /* You can change the font family here */
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #ffcc00; /* Example color */
    margin-right: 20px; /* Adds space between label and value */
  }
  
  .stat-value {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; /* You can change the font family here */
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #ffffff; /* Example color */
  }

  .trophyValue {
    font-size: 64px;
    
  }

I've tried doing it with a radial-gradient (I have it commented out) and I've tried using insets with no luck.
Heres what it looks like currently:
image of what I have now
and heres what I want, where the glow starts inbetween the icon and the number and then expands to where the glow currently is, but it stays behind the number and trophy.
Image of what I want

A background cannot go beyond the bounds of its box. You could position a larger pseudo-element behind the parent with the required background.

I'm not clear from the code you have given whether the glow is to go over subsequent elements or behind them. Could you describe a bit more what is required?

You might also, in addition to addressing the previous comments, consider adding a couple of example images showing what you have now, and what you want to have instead.

I think everything is ok, but instead use : box-shadow: 0 0 50px 10px /*color*/

@AHaworth so I want the glow to start from behind the trophy and the number, but still appear and not have a box outline like it does in the image link above. so the "glow" starts in the middle of the 3 and the Trophy in the picture. and then extends out to where it is currently at while also passing behind the trophy and the 3.
